# How can I change the program icon in Delphi/C++Builder XE7?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

In C++ Builder XE7, to set a project's icon you just go

Project > Options > Application > set the Target, click Load Icon (or Load Icns).

That's fairly straightforward, but I want to be able to switch which icon is being used based on which of, say, 3 versions of the project are going to be built (in this case, which version is determined by a const declaration in a header file, but anything similar would do).

Is there any way to change the Application > Target > Icon settings, without having to manually set the icon as well each time I switch between versions?

Comment: I'd just automate that as part of your automated build process.  This is where it pays to know how to use a good scripting language.

Comment: You do that with your own resource script. Your compiler define ("const declaration") would determine which resource file is added to the executable when it's built. Then you don't use Application->Target->Icon settings at all. (Just name your ICON resource using all CAPS, and name it something alphabetically before MAINICON.)

Comment: @KenWhite: Resource scripts also support `#ifdef` statements, so you could alternatively use a single .rc script that chooses between one of three icon files based on a conditional defined in the project.  Or you could use `{$IFDEF}`/`#ifdef` statements in your app code to compile separate .res files. Either way works.

Comment: Thanks everyone - I'll take a look at resource scripts.